# Tableau connecting to Teradata procedure with out parameters not showing

Tags: teradata, tableau-api, procedure, out-parameters

I need to save a few parameters into Teradata via Tableau, I created a Teradata procedure to do insertion but when I connect to the procedure in Tableau it kept on giving me error "xxxx stored procedure returned no result. bla bla".

In order to make stored procedure returns some result, I update the Teradata procedure to include a OUT parameter to return a dummy message, but in the list of Stored Procedures under Tableau connection, all procedures with OUT parameter are not showing.

Appreciate if anybody can help.

Comment: I don't fully understand your issue.  Is your question, "Why is my stored procedure not returning data?" or is it "Why is my stored procedure not being updated in the DB?"  Or something else...

Comment: Tableau doesn't want an OUT parameter. It wants a "dynamic result set".

Comment: @ravioli I want to use Teradata SP (perform insertion) to insert tableau parameter values into database. But when connect to the SP it kept on give me an error because my SP did not return any result (of course, it is an insertion SP). So I added a dummy OUT parameter into the SP, but now Tableau connection does not show any procedure with OUT parameter. thank you

Comment: In that case, I think Fred's answer below should do the trick since the SP will be returning a "row".  Not sure what version you're on, but take a look at the documentation for SPs:  `https://docs.teradata.com/reader/zzfV8dn~lAaKSORpulwFMg/iJLs_ICS1uy5sMPbMy4KiQ`

Answer (score 1):

Tableau does not support procedure OUT parameters. You need the procedure to return a result set, e.g.

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE myProc(someInput INTEGER,...)
...
DYNAMIC RESULT SETS 1
...
BEGIN
DECLARE csr CURSOR WITH RETURN FOR SELECT 'OK';
...
OPEN csr;
END;
```